# how to render html view in data-mathjax-bind in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In this view data mathjax is working well but when we add enter in textarea it is not going new line. when we post something like this

> ```
> a) A
> b) B
> c) C
> then it display a) A b) B c) C
> I want to display it like in data-mathjax-bind
> a) A
> b) B
> c) C
> how to solved this?
> ```

```
<div class="question-title-preview">
   <span data-mathjax-bind="question.titleDisplay"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: share mode code

Comment: Are you including the newline character after each option?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh , I am not including any newline charector in textarea . simply pressed enter key . before i used ckeditor for this but it showed as <p>sdf</p> <p>sd</p> <p>sd</p>

Comment: So when you press enter (inside the textarea), it doesn't go to the next line?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh, it goes to next line in textarea  but not showed in data-mathjax-bind(automatic typing when we typed in textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i put `$ \\ $` then it takes new line but I want through codeing
    e.g. `$ 1)abcd\\ 2)efgh $` it shows me

```
    1) abcd
    2) efgh

 how can i do it through codeing?
```